# How to push javascript variables into a mysql database with nodejs from a submit button?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

So I want to use NodeJS to push javascript variables into MySQL. I tried using the following code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
    user: "loginUSER",
    password: "xxxxx",
    database: "scoutingData"
});

function databaseCon() {
    console.log("submit works and connected.");
    con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Connected!");
      var sql = "INSERT INTO scoutingDataTab (compId, teleop_cargoTot, teleop_hatchTot) VALUES (compId, teleop_noOfCargo, teleop_noOfHatch)";
      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 record inserted");
      });
    });
}
```

Here, the variables are set at the top of the JavaScript and the databaseCon() function is called from the submit button. `compId, teleop_cargoTot, teleop_hatchTot` are columns in the database and `compId, teleop_noOfCargo, teleop_noOfHatch` are variables in the JS. I have node.js downloaded on my web server. I tried hitting submit, and an error pops up, but the page reloads too fast. How would I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the nodejs error log from "if (err) throw err;" ?

Comment: How do I get that error log? EDIT: Running Fedora 23

Comment: I recently wrote this, not sure if it helps: https://evertpot.com/executing-a-mysql-query-in-nodejs/

Answer (score -1):

If `compId, teleop_noOfCargo, teleop_noOfHatch` are variables than you need to used them. You have few options, for instance:

1. Use String interpolation:

```js
var sql = `INSERT INTO scoutingDataTab (compId, teleop_cargoTot, teleop_hatchTot) VALUES (${compId}, ${teleop_noOfCargo}, ${teleop_noOfHatch})`;
```

2. Concatenate string:

```js
var sql = "INSERT INTO scoutingDataTab (compId, teleop_cargoTot, teleop_hatchTot) VALUES (" + compId + ", " + teleop_noOfCargo + ", " + teleop_noOfHatch + ");";
```

As for now you are inserting strings `compId`, `teleop_noOfCargo`, `teleop_noOfHatch`, not variables.

Note (thanks to @Evert) there is possibility for SQL Injection. To prevent use this:

```js
var sql = "INSERT INTO scoutingDataTab (compId, teleop_cargoTot, teleop_hatchTot) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
      con.query(sql, [compId, teleop_noOfCargo , teleop_noOfHatch], function (err, result) {
```

Comment: Both your examples have SQL injection problems. This is pretty bad

Comment: It's true, but still answers the question. The question wasn't "how to proper insert data into db"

Comment: It's still a very bad suggestion. Don't answer questions unless you can actually do a proper job and teach people to do the right thing,

Comment: Sure, added note and solution without SQL injections. Thanks for noticing it ;)